# how to store objects into an arraylist?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

so i'm trying to store the object of teams in an ArrayList but gives me an error of "non-static variable store cannot be referenced from static context"

tried and searched but no luck :/

any critique of my coding skills is accepted! trying to learn can't be afraid of criticism.

```
package testing;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Testing {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    ArrayList<Team> store = new ArrayList<Team>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tourName , tourDate , location;
        int maxNumberofTeams , avalSoft, avalHard , avalFieldTest;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please Enter tournament Name?\n");
        tourName = input.next();
        System.out.print("please Enter tournament Date\n");
        tourDate = input.next();
        System.out.print("please Enter location\n");
        location = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Max number of Teams\n");
        maxNumberofTeams = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter avalSoft\n");
        avalSoft = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter aval Hard\n");
        avalHard = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter avalFieldTest\n");
        avalFieldTest = input.nextInt();
        Tournament tour = new Tournament (tourName , tourDate, location , maxNumberofTeams, avalSoft , avalHard, avalFieldTest);
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= maxNumberofTeams ; i++)
        {
            String teamName , sponsoringSchool , financialSponsor , judgeLocation;
            int teamNumber , noOfTeamMem;
            System.out.print("Please Enter %s team Name\n");
            teamName = input.next();
            System.out.print("Number of Team Memebers\n");
            noOfTeamMem = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Please Enter Sponsoring Schoolr\n");
            sponsoringSchool = input.next();
            System.out.print("Please Enter financialSponsor\n");
            financialSponsor = input.next();
            System.out.print("Please Enter judge Location\n");
            judgeLocation = input.next();
            teamNumber = i;

            Team team = new Team(teamName , teamNumber , noOfTeamMem , sponsoringSchool , financialSponsor, judgeLocation);
            store.add(team);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a non-static member from a static context: `main()` is a static method which means that it is a method of the class and it can see only class variables (static).

The way you declared `store` - it's an instance member, meaning, it "lives" in an instance of the class.

There are two ways you can access `store` from `main()`: the first is to declare it as static, and the second is to instantiate a new class instance and use it to access its own private copy of `store`.

Comment: @Ankosh your question in the comment above is unclear. Please explain.

Comment: it says the collection is only add to never read from @alfasin

Comment: @Ankosh in your case it's true but not something that the compiler is supposed to tell you. What exactly "says" this thing? which tools are you using ? what is the exact phrasing?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access a non-static (instance) field from within a `static` context.

Create a method in your `Testing` class, place the logic for your program within it.  In you `main` method, create an instance of `Testing` and call this method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Testing testing = new Testing();
    testing.makeItSo();
}

public void makeItSo() {
    String tourName , tourDate , location;
    int maxNumberofTeams , avalSoft, avalHard , avalFieldTest;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter tournament Name?\n");
    tourName = input.next();
    System.out.print("please Enter tournament Date\n");
    tourDate = input.next();
    System.out.print("please Enter location\n");
    location = input.next();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Max number of Teams\n");
    maxNumberofTeams = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please Enter avalSoft\n");
    avalSoft = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter aval Hard\n");
    avalHard = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please Enter avalFieldTest\n");
    avalFieldTest = input.nextInt();
    Tournament tour = new Tournament (tourName , tourDate, location , maxNumberofTeams, avalSoft , avalHard, avalFieldTest);
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= maxNumberofTeams ; i++)
    {
        String teamName , sponsoringSchool , financialSponsor , judgeLocation;
        int teamNumber , noOfTeamMem;
        System.out.print("Please Enter %s team Name\n");
        teamName = input.next();
        System.out.print("Number of Team Memebers\n");
        noOfTeamMem = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter Sponsoring Schoolr\n");
        sponsoringSchool = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please Enter financialSponsor\n");
        financialSponsor = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please Enter judge Location\n");
        judgeLocation = input.next();
        teamNumber = i;

        Team team = new Team(teamName , teamNumber , noOfTeamMem , sponsoringSchool , financialSponsor, judgeLocation);
        store.add(team);
    }
}
```

See [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details

Comment: can't i just declare an Arraylist of objects inside the main method?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use the `ArrayList` any where else within the class (without the need to pass it as a parameter), but that would come down to your needs, this just solves the immediate problem based on what it appears you are trying to do.  Personally, I prefer to "get out of" any `static` context as soon as possible, but that's me

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

ArrayList store = new ArrayList();

to

static ArrayList store = new ArrayList();

as because main is a static method, thus variables used inside should also be static.

Comment: *"You need to change"* not really, I would say "can", but then, I wouldn't recommend introducing the concept of `static` fields as they introduce a bunch of bad habits, but that's just me